# Can lamb chops be light fried\sauteed to fully done and how long does it take?

Tags: frying, lamb

I always thought sauteeing or pan frying with 1-2 tablespoons of oil was for thin cuts of meat.  As such it isnt suited for lamb chops.

I've been watching some videos on youtube they sautee the chops or pan fry them seemingly quickly but they dont mention how long they cooked it for or if the meat is fully cooked or not.  However in some videos I notice they mention it's medium rare but I need it to be fully cooked.

Since frying with a little oil is simple I'd like to do that rather than grill, bake, stew etc, but I need the meat to be fully cooked.  Can this be done with sauteeing or pant frying(1-2 tablespoons oil) and if so, how long do I need to cook each side.  Also if you can fry them for a short time like minutes why does broiling\grilling etc take so much longer? As far as I can see the chops do fry in a thin layer of their own fat when broiling.

Comment: Sauté is high heat cooking.  You'll burn the outside before the middle gets to well done.  In my opinion, baking is easier.  (but I also have a probe thermometer so I can set an alarm when it's time to pull it)

Comment: Are you saying it can't be done?  what if you use a little oil and cook on a low heat?  or perhaps all the videos are intending medium rare then? just to calrify i said saute but also little oil and pan fry which could be done slowly.

Comment: Struggling to see how baking (put meat on tray, put in hot oven until done, remove) is less simple than having to stand over a pan and constantly turn the meat over to stop it burning...

Comment: @JamesWilson if you use little oil and low heat, it is not called sauté.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall If you only need to pan fry for a much shorter time than say baking then it would be more simple\convinient for say those on the go.

Comment: @rumtscho I didn't know that it seems sautee means high heat pan frying with a little oil.  In any case I think I mentioned\have edited the question to include low oil pan frying of any temperature\duration.

Comment: Which cut are your lamb chops?  E.g., loin chops, rib chops, shoulder chops? And how thick are they?

Answer (score 1):

If you're aiming for fully done, it may be best to *not* try to cook too fast. If you use high heat, and your chops are reasonably thick, then by the time the center is fully done, the outside will be overcooked. High heat and thick cuts works much better when you're aiming for, say, medium rare, so that you aren't trying to heat the center as much and thus don't need to overcook the outside as much to get it there. (Maybe this is why you thought pan-cooking was for thin cuts only?)

You can avoid this by cooking on lower heat for a longer period, possibly even adding a bit of liquid and covering so that it braises/steams and heats from all sides, not just the bottom. Then, if you also wanted the browning from cooking on high heat, you can increase the heat briefly at the end. (If you used water, make sure it's all cooked off or that won't work.)

Overall, the time to cook will depend on the thickness. It might generally be faster in a pan than broiling (UK grilling) because the meat's in direct contact with a hot pan, so there's faster heat transfer. But specifics of course depend on how close you're getting to the element when broiling and how hot you have your pan.

Answer (score 0):

Just bring the heat down. I would cover the pan. It will probably take like 20 minutes.  Since the heat is low you can use another liquid like a broth or tomato.